# Why does a phase shift happen in the demodulated AM signal using envelope detection?

Tags: modulation, demodulation, telecommunications, amplitude-modulation

I was studying  AM signal demodulation using envelope detection with the circuit shown below.

In the book it says the low pass filter part is called a post-detection filter and that this filter causes a phase difference between the original signal and the output signal.

I don't quite grasp why this phase difference happens.

Can someone enlighten me?

[image]

**The text from the book:**
[image]

Comment: I think we need this reference nailed down more precisely rather than your words potentially reinterpreting what was said with some error or nuance omitted. Post a picture of the text that you read. You also need to attribute the picture already shown to the source.

Comment: @Andyaka I added the text from the book, but unfortunately, there is no picture about this topic in the book.

Comment: I think it's poorly written. It doesn't really introduce a phase shift but rather a distortion of the demodulated signal if the time constant is too long. You **MUST** give references for the text and the picture.

Comment: The phase shift will be that associated with the RC filter. Note that the relevant R will be different when the diode is conducting, hence non-linear and signal-dependent.